# Центрирование блока на сайте

Tags: css

Нужна помощь с центровкой, есть блок на сайте, и он при отдалении уезжает по максимуму влево, как это поправить? `margin:0 auto;` не помогает, блок `div_1`

```css
#DIV_1 {
  color: rgb(96, 118, 154);
  height: 1192px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(96, 118, 154);
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(96, 118, 154);
  perspective-origin: 747px 596px;
  transform-origin: 747px 596px;
  caret-color: rgb(96, 118, 154);
  border: 0px none rgb(96, 118, 154);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 25.6px "Varela Round";
  outline: rgb(96, 118, 154) none 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  height: 1192px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  perspective-origin: 747px 596px;
  transform-origin: 747px 596px;
  caret-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background-image: url('../img/12345.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 0px none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 25.6px "Varela Round";
  outline: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
  background-position: calc(-177.87px + 100%) 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  height: 1192px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: auto;
  column-rule-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  perspective-origin: 747px 596px;
  transform-origin: 747px 596px;
  caret-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  /*  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://xenium.pro/images/yootheme/home-portfolio-texture.svg") no-repeat scroll calc(-177.87px + 100%) 50% / auto padding-box border-box;*/
  background-position: right border: 0px none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 25.6px "Varela Round";
  outline: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 210px;
}


/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_4 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  height: 456px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: auto;
  column-rule-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  perspective-origin: 740px 228px;
  transform-origin: 740px 228px;
  caret-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 0px none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 25.6px "Varela Round";
  margin: 0px 7px 140px;
  outline: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}


/*#DIV_4*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    <div id="DIV_3">
      <div id="DIV_4">
        <div id="DIV_5">
          <div id="DIV_6">
            <div id="DIV_7">
              <h1 id="H1_8">
                December 2018<br id="BR_9" />
              </h1>
              <h2 id="H2_10">
                <sub id="SUB_11">REPORT</sub>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_12">
            <div id="DIV_13">
              <div id="DIV_14">
                <h3 id="H3_15">
                  DIVIDENDS
                </h3>
                <div id="DIV_16">
                  Dividends (50%): € 3 441,93

                </div>
                <div id="DIV_17">
                  <p id="P_18">
                    Dividends per 1000 EFFM: € 0,02


                  </p>
                  <p id="P_19">
                    Private investors ROI : 0,57%

                  </p>
                  <p id="P_20">
                    Common investors ROI : 0,38%

                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_25">
        <div id="DIV_26">
          <div id="DIV_27" class="line">
            <div id="DIV_28">
              <h3 id="H3_29">
                Mining Profit

              </h3>
              <div id="DIV_30">
                Mined Cryptocurrencies
              </div>
              <div id="DIV_31">
                <p id="P_32">
                  6074.68 ETC<br id="BR_33" /><span id="SPAN_34">(=228.407968 ETH)</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_35">
            <div id="DIV_36" class="line1">
              <h4 id="H4_37">
                Trading Profit
              </h4>
              <div id="DIV_38">
                Mining Costs
              </div>
              <div id="DIV_39">
                <p id="P_40">
                  1961.1 ETC<br id="BR_41" /><span id="SPAN_42">(=73.73736 ETH)</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="DIV_43">
            <div id="DIV_44">
              <h4 id="H4_45">
                EFFM Costs
              </h4>
              <div id="DIV_46">
                (12% of Net income)
              </div>
              <div id="DIV_47">
                <p id="P_48">
                  18.56047296 ETH
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="DIV_49">
            <div id="DIV_50">
              <h4 id="H4_51">
                Net Profit
              </h4>
              <div id="DIV_52">
                dividends &amp; reinvestment
              </div>
              <div id="DIV_53">
                <p id="P_54">
                  136.11013504 ETH
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_55">
        <div id="DIV_56">
          <!--
           <div id="DIV_57">
            <h2 id="H2_58">
              <a href="/lets-talk.html" id="A_59">Our miners</a>
            </h2>
            <div id="DIV_60">
             <ul id="UL_61">
              <li id="LI_62">
               AMD RX 580 : 50
              </li>
              <li id="LI_63">
               Custom FPGA : 195
              </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
           -->
          <!--
           <div id="DIV_64">
            <h2 id="H2_65">
              <a href="/lets-talk.html" id="A_66">Token Sold (10th of December)</a>
            </h2>
            <div id="DIV_67">
             <ul id="UL_68">
              <li id="LI_69">
               757265.9
              </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
           -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас резиновая ширина:

```
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Задайте значение меньше 100% и блок отцентрируется

Comment: Блок просто уменьшается по ширине, но он все равно также прижат к левому боку

Comment: как сделать, чтоб блок на всех разрешениях выглядел одинаково?